Movie where a killer robot merges with a man underwater
It is a pre-2000s killer robot movie set in some kind of enclosed facility. It has a similar vibe to Virus (1999) and Leviathan (1989). I watched it when I was a kid, way back in the 90s, so please pardon the sparse detail. 
All I remember is this scene which I think is near the end of the movie:
The killer robot was hunting for survivors (there were at least 2: a man and a woman) along a stretch of corridor. It then fell through a hole in the corridor, into a deep pool of water. One of the male survivors then sacrificed himself by jumping into the water and merging with the robot underwater. When the robot resurfaced, it looked malfunctioned and then self-destructed. The woman managed to escape as a result of the sacrifice.

when you say "merged" to you actually mean that the robot and the man somehow became fused into one being?  Or do you simply mean that the man jumped down to attack the robot and they fought underwater?

@Steve-O They fused into one. The robot disintegrated into small parts and attached itself onto the man's body.

You are probably thinking of Saturn 3. Check Trailer if robot looks familiar.
They are not merged and it was not deep pool of water but some very cold liquid. Robot falls in twice. First time it is pushed and comes out frozen but still working. Second time is with male and explosion so that's where you get parts flying around. Could be you mixed up these falls into one in your memory. 

Yes that's the one! My memory of the movie certainly got fuzzy over the years. Thank you so much Marko!
